# @smithy/types build issue in angular

Tags: angular, dependencies, node-modules, ng-build

My angular application failed during the time of build. Below is the error that I am getting.

ERROR in node_modules/@smithy/types/dist-types/ts3.4/extensions/checksum.d.ts:23:6 - error TS1337: An index signature parameter type cannot be a union type. Consider using a mapped object type instead.

23     [other: string | number]: any;

My angular version: 10.2.4,
node: 14.21.3,
typescript: 3.9.4,
@smithy/types : tried all versions.

I tried all versions of @smithy/types, changed tsc versions also but nothing resolved my issue. Earlier I had same issue with tsc version 4.0 then I resolved it with usinng tsc version 3.9.1 and installing smithy and @smithy/types package. Dont know what causes this issue and how to resolve it.

Comment: have you tried with the latest `2.2.1` ? https://github.com/awslabs/smithy-typescript/issues/865

Comment: Yes @MatthieuRiegler. Already tried with that. Tried with all of them.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: it got resolved by adding "skipLibCheck": true to tsconfig.json